# grey background Bing Maps

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I have a problem with my first stand alone application with Bing Maps

**Key Creation**

I have gone on `https://www.bingmapsportal.com` to create my key

I used "Basic" key type, "windows store app" as application type and `http://localhost` as application URL

**Libs**

as request I downloded this lib `http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27165` and I added it as resource in my project

**Code**

I creaded new project (with .net V4) and i wrote this code

```
<Window x:Class="WorldMapViewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1000" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing">
<Grid Name="wm_container">
    <m:Map CredentialsProvider="_MY_KEY_" Center="37.806029,-122.407007" ZoomLevel="16"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

when i run that it shows bing logo, mile scale and nothing else...i see only an orrible grey background...where i wrong??

Comment: Seems your application is not a Windows Store App, but WPF instead. Not sure if you can use your Bing Maps API Key for that. There are alternative map controls that do not require an API key.

Comment: What are alternative map controls? I followed this url `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx#bmtou` and Windows Store App seems the best fits.

Comment: You may use `Not-for-profit` or `Education` for your API key type. An alternative map control may be [this](http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/).

Comment: are you using MercatorMode, this has no tile layer hence its black.  Whats your c# codebehind? If not, try setting mode to RoadMode or trying adding a tile layer of a map to the control.